# re.compile pasing mutliple pattern for match string

Tags: python-2.7

I have to search multiple string in text. is it possible to search multiple pattern in one compile statement.

```
text_data = """Errors err:
               err
               Error"""

comp = re.compile('Error err') #
comp.search(text_data)
```

One options is to create list in following way  but In my case text_data is huge file and I have to repeat this multiple times.

```
regexes = [ re.compile(p) for p in [ 'Error',
                                     'err',
                                     'Error err'
                                     ]
            ]
for regex in regexes:
    if regex.search(text_text_data):
        print 'found a match!'
```

Comment: You know a regex can use `|` for *"or"*?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pipe (`|`) in regular expressions to combine multiple expressions, requiring only one to match at a given point. For example `A|B` will match `A` or `B`.

You can also do this without capturing groups, so for example `A(B|C)D` will match `ABD` and `ACD`.

In your case, you can simply combine your three parts to the following expression:

```
Error|err|Error err
```

Example:

```
>>> r = re.compile('Error|Error err|err')
>>> r.findall(text_data)
['Error', 'err', 'err', 'Error']
```

(Remember that `re.search` will only give you the first match it finds, so I’m using `re.findall` here).